# Can I access a mysql database from a Sharepoint 2013 page?

Tags: javascript

I've recently figured out how to add, remove, update list items on a Sharepoint site using javascript.

**But can I access a mysql database from a Sharepoint 2013 page using javascript?**

I want to query the mysql database in order to retrieve information form a table and print it on a page or insert it in a list. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think, you can do it via Javascript but You can take the advanatge of the BCS services and connect to the MySQL, then retrieve the information.

BCS enable you to create External Content Types and External Lists from SQL Server Database or Webservice.

You will find a complete guide on MSDN right here.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee556431(v=office.14).aspx

With Microsoft SharePoint Designer 2013, you can connect to any kind of database, including Microsoft SQL Server (SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2008), Oracle, and OLE DB protocol.

[How to Create Data Sources Using SharePoint Designer 2013, Part I: Saving User Name & Password](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2012/09/24/how-to-create-data-sources-using-sharepoint-designer-2013-part-i.aspx)

Comment: You will need to write a web service which will expose the data from your MySQL database. Then you can consume that web service and play around with the data on a sharepoint page.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for answering. Do you have a similar method for connecting to a MySQL server (not MSSQL)? I tried connecting from Sharepoint Designer using a custom connection string (having the ODBC driver installed) but couldn't manage to connect.

Comment: You can find my attempts and the error at the link below. Please be so kingd and help me >:D< http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/136881/connect-to-mysql-using-sharepoint-designer-2013-error